# mx:TextArea vertical scroll bar disabled

Tags: actionscript-3, mxml

I have a `TextArea` component as follows:

```
    <mx:TextArea
        id="textArea"
        width="100%"
        height="100%"
        editable="false"
        verticalScrollPolicy="on"
    />
```

My issue is that I populate the TextArea with a huge amount of text that needs to be scrolled through. The vertical scrollbar exists, but is disabled. Even though it is disabled the user can scroll using the mouse scroll.

Note: If I change the text later the scrollbar reenables.

Comment: See [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37347998/how-to-add-vertical-scroll-bars-on-textarea-in-actionscript-3)

Answer (score 0):

The fix turned out simply using the `spark` component instead of `mx` component:

```
    <s:TextArea
        id="textArea"
        width="100%"
        height="100%"
        editable="false"/>
```

Comment: I recommend doing this whenever possible. There are too many issues with the mx components