# How to add vertical scroll bars on textarea in Actionscript 3?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4

I wants to add vertical scroll bar in textarea spark component, i.e I want to show maximum 5 lines in textarea if text line will more than 5 then vertical scroll bar will automatically add and if i will reduce the text line then vertical scroll bar will automatically disappear.

My textarea code is :

```
<s:TextArea id="txtArea" width="{this.width}" height="3" borderVisible="false" focusAlpha="0.01" 
            selectionHighlighting="always" styleName="TextBox"
            needsSoftKeyboard="true" focusRect="false" direction="{textBoxDirction}" buttonMode="true" useHandCursor="true" mouseChildren="true"/>
```

I also tried to use `verticalScrollPolicy = "on" and "off"` but it is also not working.

So if anybody have an idea how to add vertical scroll bar in textarea please help me to solve this problem.

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
heightInLines="5"
```

instead of

```
height="3"
```

Answer (score 0):

Just put the `mx:TextArea` with `width="100%"` inside a `mx:VBox` container with  a fixed height.